# Retrieving Folder icon from operating system for tree view in mfc

Tags: mfc

I am trying to get folder icon in tree view from operating system using SHGetFileInfo().
But I am not able to get the folder icon in tree view.

I Created tree view using CSplitterWnd.

```
TVINSERTSTRUCT tvInsert;
HTREEITEM hCategory;
SHFILEINFO sfi;

tvInsert.hParent = NULL;
tvInsert.hInsertAfter = NULL;

tvInsert.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM| TVIF_IMAGE ;

::SHGetFileInfo(pRoot->GetName(), 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES|SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX|SHGFI_SMALLICON);

tvInsert.item.lParam =(LPARAM) pRoot; 
tvInsert.item.pszText = (LPWSTR)pRoot->GetName().GetString();
tvInsert.item.iImage = sfi.iIcon;
hCategory= GetTreeCtrl().InsertItem(&tvInsert);
```

but i am not able to get the folder icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your specific issue is, but I use the following code to cache the folder image:

```
TCHAR szWindows[MAX_PATH+1] = { 0 };
GetWindowsDirectory(szWindows, MAX_PATH);

SHFILEINFO sfi = { 0 };

UINT nFlags = SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | (m_bLargeIcons ? SHGFI_ICON : SHGFI_SMALLICON);
HIMAGELIST hIL = (HIMAGELIST)SHGetFileInfo(szWindows, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), nFlags);

nFolderImage = sfi.iIcon;
```

Comment: Thanx for help me out from this problem.